# Math writing from code- how to write equations?

Tags: article-writing

I have written code (in R) for my research project and am trying to publish a paper. Is there a good guide on how to take the concepts in my code and write them in a paper mathematically?

Specifically, I have two questions:

1. How do I write that a number has to be a divisor? Is it: If a|b, then... where a is one of the divisors of b?
2. If I have an array of indices v, how do I define the values of another array, G, at the index values $\bar{v}$? Is it: $G_{v}= \ $ or maybe $G_{\bar{v}}= \ $?

For example, in my project, objects exist along an axis Z. They occur only when a value is a divisor of the maximum value of an object along Z. Therefore, if $v_{max}$ occurs on Z, then vector $\bar{v}$ is all divisors of $v_{max}$. Also $\bar{v}$ represents the occurrences of all objects along the Z axis. The G values depend on the location of the occurrences, $\bar{v}$. G in the code is defined at these locations. In R, v is a vector and G is a vector. Defining G in R would read as:

```
G[seq(1,length(v)] = function(v)
```

G is therefore a function of v, but how would I reference G at a particular v?

Comment: Are you asking how to make your _code_ more readable to mathematician, or take the concepts in your code, and write them in a paper mathematically?

Comment: Take the concepts in my code and write them in a paper mathematically

Comment: Also, what language are you writing in? What does your supervisor recommend? You may want to add the relevant tags, or maybe even ask the question on LanguageUsed.SE (which exists for Sage/Mathematica and should do for quite a few other mathematical programming languages)

Comment: what thoughts have you had so far about this problem? Personally, i would look at how various algorithms have been presented in arXiv, find a paper which develops some sort of algorithmic solution and see how it is presented there (or a different sort, depending on what you have found)

Comment: a paper isn't a program. If you can convey an important idea clearly with plain text, you should probably just write plain text. Also, very few people like to read (pseudo) code longer than a page...

Comment: You should write instead (in 5 lines) a paragraph you care about, and we will rewrite it with the preferred notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your very specific questions

> 1)

One would indeed write $a \mid b$ for $a$ divides $b$. However as a general rule, you can find common notation just by searching the English aspect in a search engine.
For instance, searching "Divisor mathematics" gets you to [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor), which 4 lines down in the definition part says $a \mid b$. After that, deciphering the correct $\LaTeX$ code can be done by [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

> 2)

Ultimately you can choose the notation you like. Personally, it would depend on the number of times and density I use the character. If it is dense at a particular page or few then maybe the latter $G_{ \bar v}$. However, if I have to use the symbol often, then I would prefer $G_v$ purely because it looks less squashed. If I refer to $\bar v$ a lot and then have to refer to $G_v$, I might the first time use $G_{ \bar v}$ and explain that I'll also use $G_v$.

It would appear, from the above paragraph at least, that you have some rigorous construction for this $G_v$. So, you might want to start off with an introduction as to why your paper is worth my half-day of reading and digesting the material. This could include a problem that is initially unsolved that the new $G_v$ solves. Then you might want to define standard terms and then construct the $G_v$ giving lemmas of various properties that $G_v$ might hold. You don't need to give every step, but at various points just reference an algorithm you use and say "Using the Gram-Schmidt algorithm, we can find a vector $w$ which has a bunch of cool properties" (or something along those lines). Other examples would be "From methods discussed in [CoolGuy15], we can find $H_v$ which acts as an intermediate step for finding $G_v$."

One author that comes to mind is [Dan Yasaki](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.1762.pdf), with these particular papers [Perfect Forms](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.3130.pdf) and [Bianchi Forms](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.1762.pdf). Particularly in the second paper, there is a problem discussed and solved by work done in chapter 2 and 3, relying on algorithmic work done in Gunnels' papers.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the help. Definitely my end goal is to get the point across to the reader, so I reference particular G values. My writing is very similar to the examples, so I'm glad the notations made some sense at least without the rest of the context